# Control how split breaks up "empty" sections

Tags: java, split

Here is my string ....
          ~abc~~def~~~b~~~

I want to split this string by (~). Using simple simple I not able to get the last part as blank/null.

output m looking for..

```
null
abc
null
null
def
null
null
null
b
null
null
null
```

Comment: What you want to do is not what is known as string splitting. You want a function that prints null every time it finds ~ ?

Comment: "Using simple simple" did you mean "Using simple split"?

Comment: quite strange indeed maybe a bug in java.

the output is:
 '', 'abc', '', 'def', '', '', 'b'

for code:
String S="~abc~~def~~~b~~~";
String s[]=S.split("[~]");
for(String ss : s)
System.out.println("'"+ss+"', ");

Answer (score 2):

`split` doesn't return `null`, but `""` empty strings. Also by default it removes empty trailing strings from result array. If you want to turn off this optimization use `split(regex,limit)` with negative `limit` like

```
text.split("~", -1)
```

But notice that split produces empty elements only *between delimiters*. So in case of part of text like `~~~` and delimiter `~` it will produce only two blank strings. If you really want to produce three blank spaces you could use something like

```
text.split("~|(?<=~)(?<!^~|~$)", -1)
```

Idea of this regex is to split not only on `~` but also in place which is right after last `~` in a group of delimiters like `~~` to add blank string. Problem with this approach is such blank strings are not necessary when we are splitting on `~` placed at start or end of string, so we need to avoid this tildes.

To make it all possible I used [look-around mechanism](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), or to be more precise, look-behind `(?<=...)` and negative-look-behind `(?<!...)`. These mechanism will check if right before current place exist/doesn't exist match for regex specified in `...` part.

So `~|(?<=~)(?<!^~|~$)` will split on

- `~` each tilde character
- `|` OR
- `(?<=~)` place which has `~` before it,

  - `(?<!^~|~$)` but is not after:

    - `^~` tilde which is at start of our string (represented by `^` anchor),
    - or `~$` placed at the end of our string (represented by `$` anchor).

DEMO:

```
String text = "~abc~~def~~~b~c~~~";
for (String s : text.split("~|(?<=~)(?<!^~|~$)", -1)) {
    System.out.println("'" + s + "'");
}
```

Output:

```
''
'abc'
''
''
'def'
''
''
''
'b'
''
'c'
''
''
''
```

Comment: This doesn't quite produce the output OP wants. In particular, the sequence "abc~~def" will only produce one empty string in the middle, not two, and "def~~~b" will only produce two empty strings, not three.

Comment: @yshavit Yes, but I assumed that this is expected behavior since OP mentioned only problem with lack of trailing elements. Anyway will try to update with better solution.

Comment: Bravo! That's some nice regex'ing, there. Thanks for the @-mention to remind me to look. :) OP, my one additional suggestion would be to add a comment if you use this, explaining the regex or at least linking back here. Otherwise it may be hard to understand what the regex does if you have to revisit it later.

Answer (score 1):

You can't return null, but maybe this can help you.

```
String str = "~abc~~def~~~b~~~";
str = str.replaceAll("~", "-");

char[] chars = str.toCharArray();
for (int i =0; i < chars.length; i++)
{
    String check = Character.toString(chars[i]);
    if(check.contentEquals("-"))
    {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(check);
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.print(check);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

how about:

Use String tokenizer to split strings in Java without split:

```
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class tt {
    public static void main(String a[]){
        String s = "012ab567ab0123ab";
        String delims = "ab ";
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(s, delims);
        System.out.println("No of Token = " + st.countTokens());
        while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
            System.out.println(st.nextToken());
        }
    }
}
```

or use your split function

```
public class MySplit {

public static String[] mySplit(String text,String delemeter){
    java.util.List<String> parts = new java.util.ArrayList<String>();
    text+=delemeter;        

    for (int i = text.indexOf(delemeter), j=0; i != -1;) {
        parts.add(text.substring(j,i));
        j=i+delemeter.length();
        i = text.indexOf(delemeter,j);
    }


    return parts.toArray(new String[0]);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str="012ab567ab0123ab";
    String delemeter="ab";
    String result[]=mySplit(str,delemeter);
    for(String s:result)
        System.out.println(s);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To omit blank/null, you can use `Guava`:

```
Iterable<String> strs = Splitter.on('~').omitEmptyStrings().split(toSplit);
```

Comment: "*I not able to get the last part as blank/null*" so it looks like OP doesn't want to omit empty strings.